# issues regarding textboxes

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have two textboxes which binds to the same property. One textbox is for the original text, the second is for the new text. What I'm having issue is, when the first textbox's text gets submitted, it returns the original text. But when I type in the second textbox to update the name, this automatically override what's in the first textbox's text. I was just wondering if there's anyway of stopping this so I'll have original and new text displaying.

```
    <TextBox Name="txtOriginalName" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Width="524" Height="auto" TextWrapping="Wrap"  
             AcceptsReturn="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
             Text="{Binding Path=Person.Name}"/>

   <TextBox Name="txtNewName" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="524" Height="auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" 
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
            Text="{Binding Path=Person.Name}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Text="{Binding Path=Person.Name, Mode=OneTime}"` for txtOriginalName, then txtOriginalName will be initialised to the value in Person.Name, but won't be updated when Person.Name changes later.

Here's a useful binding [cheat sheet](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf)

Comment: No, just for the one that you only want to bind once (the "original" one)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you have a PersonViewModel that has separate OriginalName and NewName properties, with some trigger condition that determines when the underlying Person.Name is updated.  This also allows you to put UI-level validation logic (with associated feedback) if certain name entries are invalid.  You're essentially decoupling the process of updating a Name (with a notion of New/Original names) from the process of containing a Name.  The former can be in a state where the Name is in the process of changing, whereas the latter simply has a Name.